# Webservice behaviour changes with VB and C#

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, serialization, soap

I am trying to communicate with a webservice over SOAP method. The code works with C# and not with VB. Which is strange, I need it to work with VB. Any ideas?

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wsdltest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        hpsm.APSServer_Service apsServer = new hpsm.APSServer_Service();
        int serviceReturn = 24081987;
        var aTime = new hpsm.Timing();
        aTime.id = "something";
        aTime.endMillis = 100;
        aTime.startMillis = 0;
        aTime.subsystem = "aSubsystem";
        aTime.threadID = "someThreadID";


        var timing = new hpsm.Timing[] { aTime };
        var message = "this is a message";
        var payload = "payload";
        var status = 24081987;

        hpsm.service("testOp", "correlationID", "version", "environment", true, out serviceReturn, ref payload, out status, out message, out timing);



        Console.WriteLine("service return = " +serviceReturn);
        Console.WriteLine("message = " +message);
        Console.WriteLine("status = " +status);
        Console.WriteLine("timing = " + timing);
        Console.WriteLine("payload = " + payload);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

VB

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim hpsm As hpsm.APSServer_Service = New hpsm.APSServer_Service()

        Dim serviceReturn As Integer = 24081987

        Dim message As String = "this is a message"
        Dim payload As String = "payload"
        Dim status = 24081987

        Dim aTime = New hpsm.Timing()
        aTime.id = "something"
        aTime.endMillis = 100
        aTime.startMillis = 0
        aTime.subsystem = "aSubsystem"
        aTime.threadID = "someThreadID"

        Dim timingArray() As hpsm.Timing = {aTime}

        ' call WebService

        hpsm.service("testop", "correlationid", "version", "enviornment", True, serviceReturn, payload, status, message, timingArray)



    End Sub

End Module
```

ERROR

```
(from Visual Studio 2017)
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There was an error generating the XML document.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Serialize(SoapClientMessage message)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at wsdlVB.hpsm.APSServer_Service.service(String operationName, String correlationID, String version, String environment, Boolean respTimeMonitoring, Int32& serviceReturn, String& payload, Int32& status, String& message, Timing[]& timings) in C:\Users\admhishaam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wsdlVB\wsdlVB\Web References\hpsm\Reference.vb:line 87
       at wsdlVB.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\admhishaam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wsdlVB\wsdlVB\Module1.vb:line 24
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2147467262
       Message=Specified cast is not valid.
       Source=021yt0yo
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAPSServer_Service.Write5_service(Object[] p)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer5.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
       InnerException:
```

From among the parameters I pass to the "hpsm.service" method, it seems that on VB it is not happy with the parameter 'timing', and complains that it is not able to serialize it. 'timing' is a custom class of that method. Here is the method

```
Public Sub service(ByVal operationName As String, ByVal correlationID As String, ByVal version As String, ByVal environment As String, ByVal respTimeMonitoring As Boolean, ByRef serviceReturn As Integer, ByRef payload As String, ByRef status As Integer, ByRef message As String, ByRef timings() As Timing)
            Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("service", New Object() {operationName, correlationID, version, environment, respTimeMonitoring, payload})
            serviceReturn = CType(results(0),Integer)
            payload = CType(results(1),String)
            status = CType(results(2),Integer)
            message = CType(results(3),String)
            timings = CType(results(4),Timing())
        End Sub
```

Which is a bit strange.

Comment: your stacktrace states that you have an invalid Cast, can you show the XML of the web method / wsdl or the SOAP method definition and the xml fields and their datatype?

Comment: These two lines are not equivalent : 1)c# -        hpsm.service("testop", "correlationid", "version", "enviornment", True, serviceReturn, payload, status, message, timingArray) 2) VB -            Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("service", New Object() {operationName, correlationID, version, environment, respTimeMonitoring, payload})

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try this converter : http://converter.telerik.com

Comment: link changed by telerik the last days